# How do I properly bind the html to the model data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So I am developing my first webpage using ASP.NET MVC and I managed to create a fully working registration page which send the data to the database and stored the user. Simple.

However I didn't really like the look and feel of the element it created for me so I thought I could change it out.

**Original code WORKING**

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**My new code NOT WORKING**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="input-group bb-none">
                    <i class="fas fa-address-card"></i>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname">
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am 99.9% sure that it's a binding issue. I want the data I put into my new textbox

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Firstname">
```

To carry over the data to the model.

What's the part that binds it in the first option?

Comment: If you inspect the HTML markup rendered by Html helper in your working code you'll notice that it adds name attribute "Firstname" used in form value send and bind to params of action method handling the submission of the form. So just add name="Firstname" to have that input add its value to form submission.

Comment: Probably the answer @AngelD - just beat me to adding the comment.

Comment: I thought it would be model.FirstName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag helpers will resolve down to html and put the property name as both the id and name within the input. The model binder then binds to that.

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.Firstname, new { placeholder = "Firstname" })
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that didn't work, `asp-for` doesnt even pop up in intellisense not sure if it's supposed to but it still gives a invalid request which happends when Firstname is missing

Comment: Sorry my bad was thinking about .net core. Updated above. EditorFor is also fine, it has the added benefit of of setting the input type based off the model type type="text" or type="number" for an int.

Comment: So rather than `<input asp-for="Firstname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname">` I should use `@Html.TextBox("Firstname")` ? I don't see how it binds

Comment: And if I were to use that how would I add the placeholder tag?

Comment: This will be a good reference for you. The initial one I gave with "Firstname" is loosely typed which means I could add anything in there, I have updated now to have a more strongly typed example which will use the Firstname from the model and the placeholder. This link is good for explaining these input fields etc http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-textbox-textboxfor

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks!